# Turn off "Parameter should be initialized" ES6 JavaScript error in Pycharm

Tags: javascript, pycharm, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm building a Redux reducer and have specified it just as in the docs:

```
function values(state = {}, action) {
    ...
}
```

However, the *action* parameter has a red underscore as if it was an error. Pycharm is reporting it as "Parameter should be initialized". I have looked in the JavaScript code inspection, but can not find anything that matches this.

Does anyone know how I can tell PyCharm not to consider this an error?

Comment: if you are using pycharm 4 or 4.5 , I don't think that it understands ES6 syntax so it will give you error messages

Comment: Oh. I use 4.5.3. Better update then. Thank you!

Comment: Pycharm 5 is available at this time, go and grap that..:)

Answer (score 0):

This is ES6 syntax. Make sure you’re running an ES6 transpiler like [Babel](http://babeljs.io) and that other tools you use also support it. As [mentioned by Zohaib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901502/turn-off-parameter-should-be-initialized-es6-javascript-error-in-pycharm#comment55565672_33901502), it seems that upgrading to PyCharm 5.x will solve your problem.

In the meantime don’t forget that default parameters are just syntax sugar.
You can write the same function like this:

```
function values(state, action) {
  if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
    return {};
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm 2018 (and probably earlier), you can specify the JavaScript version under `File > Settings > Languages&Frameworks > JavaScript`. There is a dropdown labeled "JavaScript language version":

[image: Screenshot of PyCharm settings]